# Prove that :$a_{n+2}a_n-a_{n+1}^2=2^n$ $\forall n \in N$

Tags: limits, recurrence-relations

Let $(a_n)$ with $a_0=1;a_1=3$ and
 $$a_{n+2}=\left [ \frac{a_{n+1}^2+2^n}{a_n} \right ]$$
Prove that :$a_{n+2}a_n-a_{n+1}^2=2^n$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$. Here $[x]$  means the biggest integer $<x$.

Comment: Do the square brackets mean anything?

Comment: What is $a_2$? My calculator has trouble.

Comment: ok I 've just edit

Comment: I believe that he wants $a_0=1$, which will yield the starting sequence  $1, 3, 10, 34, 116, ...$

Comment: sorry I'm hungry so many mistake when I use computer ^^

Answer (score 2):

We calculate the initial sequence and obtain $1, 3, 10, 34, 116$. This leads to the guess that $a_{n+2} = 4a_{n+1} - 2 a_n$, which has solution $a_n = \frac { (2+\sqrt{2})^{n+1} + (2-\sqrt{2})^{n+1}} {4}$.

Step 1: Verify by induction that $a_n$ has the closed form above.

Direct Step 2: Conclude that $a_{n+2}a_n -a_{n+1}^2 = 2^n$. (we're now done)

Alternative Step 2: We can also further show that $a_{n+2} = 4 a_{n+1} - 2a_n$, to conclude that each of the $a_n$ are integers, and hence the floor function isn't necessary. Thus $a_{n+2}a_n - a_{n+1}^2 = 2^n$.

Comment: I also have the same idea with you but it 's hard for me to prove that :$a_{n+2}=4a_{n+1}-2a_{n}$

Comment: @Haruboy15 I'm not proving that fact. I don't even know that it's true (as yet). I'm using that guess to motivate the closed form of $a_n$ (that I didn't pull it out from nowhere), and then verify that the closed form satisfies your functional equation.

Comment: I can claim that it's true; but I haven't proved this yet

Comment: @Haruboy15 Read carefully, we do not need that. Just do step 1 and Direct step 2. The initial paragraph is motivating the fact that $a_n$ has the closed form as described, instead of saying that I pulled it out from thin air.

Comment: The "Alternative Step" is the way to go, I guess: The explicit form fits both the linear recurrence (which preserves integers) as well as the claim to be shown, hence also the original recurrence if one drops the Gauss brackets (which does not matter as everything is integer).